# Socket Connection between iphone and mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I want to establish socket connection between iphone and mac, how to do this? Can you please help with some links or sample code.

My goal is to develop an application that will send an image file from my iphone to my mac.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variety of options:

1) http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/
To deal with a raw socket connection between your iPhone and mac.

2) http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
Run an http server on your mac and send POST requests from your iPhone with ASIHTTPRequest

3) Make use of some other protocol like ftp or smb or something.

(personally, I'd pick http, it's pretty simple to get going)